# Why do I get a NULL for this timestampdiff()?

Tags: mysql, timestampdiff

Why does the following query in MySQL result in a null for that timestampdiff()?

```
SELECT EndDate, /* EndDate is YEAR(4) datatype with value 2013 */
       year('2015-01-01') a,
       timestampdiff( YEAR, Year('2015-01-01'), EndDate) b
  FROM table
```

Results:

```
 EndDate     a     b
    2013  2015  NULL
```

Comment: My guess would be because `YEAR` is not a date or a datetime data type. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Comment: Yep. I fixed it by appending a month/day and it sees it as a datetime.

`SELECT EndDate,
  CONCAT(EndDate,'-01-01') a,
  timestampdiff(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE('2015-01-01','%Y-%m-%d'), CONCAT(EndDate,'-01-01')) d
FROM tblboard`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't automatically convert YEAR(4) datatypes to DATETIME. I fixed it by appending a month/day to EndDate and it sees it as a DATETIME.

`SELECT EndDate,
  timestampdiff(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE('2015-01-01','%Y-%m-%d'), CONCAT(EndDate,'-01-01')) d
FROM table`

Thanks to @Uueerdo for identifying the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`timestampdiff()` requires valid dates for the second and third argument. `YEAR('2015-01-01')` returns `2015`, which is not a valid date, which breaks `timestampdiff()` causing it to return NULL. Just make the second argument `'2015-01-01'` and as long as your `EndDate` is good, it should work.

Comment: As @UUeerdo figured out, it didn't convert the YEAR(4) datatype to date. I fixed it by appending a month/day and it sees it as a datetime.

`  SELECT EndDate,
  CONCAT(EndDate,'-01-01') a,
  timestampdiff(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE('2015-01-01','%Y-%m-%d'), CONCAT(EndDate,'-01-01')) d
FROM tblboard`

Answer (score 0):

Try convert the year a stingr to a valid date

```
SELECT EndDate, /* EndDate is YEAR(4) datatype with value 2013 */
   STR_TO_DATE('2015-01-01','%Y-%m-%d') a,
   timestampdiff( YEAR,  STR_TO_DATE('2015-01-01','%Y-%m-%d'), EndDate) b
FROM table
```